# Can access Github via browser but not via git commands

Tags: proxy, git, firewall, github

I work in a bank which seems to be blocking Github (they use [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) with internally hosted repos):

```
H:\>git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
Cloning into 'linux'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git/': 
Could not resolve host: github.com
```

However, I'm able to access https://github.com/torvalds/linux through the web browser.

How did the company manage to block https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git but not https://github.com/torvalds/linux?

Is there any way I can get around it? I tried `git init` and manually adding the remote url, but `git pull` still gives the same error as above.

Comment: They haven't, you just haven't told git about your companys proxy.

Comment: As previous comment says, your proxy needs your username and password which the browser sends but git does not. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Presuming you're doing this on windows, or have access to a windows machine to check the proxy settings, linux users you're on your own! ;)

Command to use:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

- change `proxyuser` to your proxy user
- change `proxypwd` to your proxy password
- change `proxy.server.com` to the URL of your proxy server
- change `8080` to the proxy port configured on your proxy server

If your proxy doesn't require logging in, use

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.server.com:8080
```

---

How do you find your proxy details? Well it varies depending how the proxy is setup, but you may find it in the system settings.

First, windows key + x,

- Click Settings,
- Click Network & Internet,
- Click Proxy....

Comment: It's using an "automatic configuration script" for the proxy, and the script returns multiple proxies: `"PROXY proxy-vip.web.**.com:PORT_NUM;PROXY cdc-proxy-vip.web.**.com:PORT_NUM"`. How should I configure multiple proxies or do I just need one? Should I configure `https.proxy` instead? How do I get the proxy user and password? (it's not in the script) I tried with my Windows login credentials, it failed with http code 407.

Comment: If no username is shown in the script then you likely don't need one. I'd suggest just trying with one proxy - I've not dealt with a script that contains two before. Also should of said this before, maybe ask your IT team?

Comment: I got an error "Received HTTP Code 407 from proxy after CONNECT" without credentials. I don't want to ask the tech support because I'm not sure if use of Git is permitted, so I can claim ignorance if I get it to work myself and get found out.

Comment: But doesn’t this store both username and password in the git config file as clear text? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Or unset proxies

```bsh
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Or do you have the proxy in the local config?

```bsh
git config --unset http.proxy
git config --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: thank you so much!